# getting error using regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Given input has 4 lines and I am supposed to find how many lines have word hacker

```
4
I love #hacker
I just scored 27 points in the Picking Cards challenge on #Hacker
I just signed up for summer cup @hacker
interesting talk by hari, co-founder of hacker
```

The answer is 4 but I get it as 0.

```
int main() {
    int count = 0,t;
    cin >> t;
    string s;
    bool ans;
    while(t--){
        cin >> s;
        smatch sm;
        regex rgx("hacker",regex_constants::icase);
        ans = regex_match(s,sm,rgx);
        if(ans){
            count += 1;
        }         
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try: `std::regex_search()` rather than `std::regex_match()` because *match* needs to match the whole sting.

Comment: `std::cin` will stop at `I`. So `getline` is what you need. Also there's a thing called a debugger

Answer (score 1):

<s>It looks like the first word is supposed to be the number of lines of input. But, even though it seems you want to process four lines of input, the input says `3`.</s><sub>Question has since been edited.</sub>

You are not reading lines, but strings, which translates into individual words. Use `getline()` to get a line of input.

```
while(t--){
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    //...
```

Your regular expression is ill-formed. It will only match if the line consists only of the word "hacker". You want to see if hacker is in the line, so make allow your pattern to match the rest of the line around the word "hacker".

```
    regex rgx(".*hacker.*",regex_constants::icase);
```

When you emit your answer, it seems you want to emit `count`, not `ans`.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Bd1sRp)</kbd>

Comment: When I use cin >> t I get 3 as answer but when I use your code it gives correct solution. Isnt cin >> t similar to getline(cin, s);
    t = stoi(s);

Comment: It shows false for the first input if I use cin >> t

Comment: `cin >> t` will leave the rest of the line after consuming the number. The first line only has a number, so the rest of the line will look like an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your while loop only runs `t` times, and every time it only reads one word. So your program right now will only read the first three words and then terminate.
2. You're only matching the whole word. In the case of `#hacker` an `@hacker`, there will be no match.
3. I believe you want to cout `count` instead of `ans` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::getline` instead to read a string (containing whitespaces).
Also, you should use `std::regex_search` to search for a 'partial' match (`std::regex_match` will only match when the regex matches the whole string).

Here's your code a little modified:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int count = 0,t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::string s;
    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex rgx("hacker", std::regex_constants::icase);

    for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        while(std::regex_search(s, sm, rgx))
        {  
            ++count;
            s = sm.suffix().str();
        }
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your regex as follows, you will get expected result:

```
regex rgx("(.*)hacker(.*)",regex_constants::icase);
```

So it is basically comparing for the match in whole string.

Otherwise you have to use `std::regex_search` in place of `std::regex_match`

```
ans = regex_search(s,sm,rgx);
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f28c2e4b315f6f0a